# Cannot remove file from Linux filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, root

I have this file and I cannot get it removed from the filesystem:

```
[root@ad Windows10]# ls -las
total 16
8 drwxrwx---+  2 root    root  4096 Jul 30 10:19 .
8 drwxrwx---+ 12 3000024 users 4096 Jul 30 10:19 ..
0 -rw-rw----+  1 root    root     0 Jul 30 10:19 Win10HomX86.iso

[root@ad Windows10]# rm -rf Win10HomX86.iso

[root@ad Windows10]# ls -las

total 16
8 drwxrwx---+  2 root    root  4096 Jul 30 10:20 .
8 drwxrwx---+ 12 3000024 users 4096 Jul 30 10:19 ..
0 -rw-rw----+  1 root    root     0 Jul 30 10:20 Win10HomX86.iso
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that the directory is mounted over the network from elsewhere (judging by the insanely high user ID of the parent directory)?

Comment: Please add the output of "mount" and "pwd" to the post